# how to make each word in an array move separately from each other in processing?

Tags: java, arrays, string, processing

I know this is a logical error but I have this program that I want 50 random words to show and those 50 should EACH spread out and will move in random places, but instead, I keep getting 50 random words all at once per frame and all of them are overlapping each other and then going to random places.. what did I do wrong in my code?

here is how I did it:

```
 String [] allWords;
 int index = 0 ;
 float x;
 float y; 


void setup () {

size (500,500);
background (255); //background : white

String [] lines = loadStrings ("alice_just_text.txt"); //imports the 
external file
String text = join(lines, " "); //make into one long string
allWords = splitTokens (text, ",.?!:-;:()03 "); //splits it by word

x = 100; //where they start 
y = 150; 

}


void draw() {

background (255);

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {  //produces 50 words

  x = x + random (-3,3); //makes the words move or shake
  y = y + random (-3,3); //makes the words move or shake

  int index = int(random(allWords.length));  //random selector of words

  textSize (random(10,80)); //random font sizes
  fill (0); //font color: black
  textAlign (CENTER,CENTER);
  text (allWords[index], x, y, width/2, height/2); 
  println(allWords[index]); 
  index++ ;


 }

}
```

Comment: What did you mean in the line:  x = x + random (-3,3); ?  How you control the numbers which is free to be filled?

Comment: it's what they make the words move or shake @VasylLyashkevych

Comment: Yes, I think you cannot to compile your code, and you use -3 as one of a boundary. Did you consider any the same algorithms? You can use: x = x + random.nextInt(3);

Comment: I think I did not use -3 as a boundary? I used -3 so the words could either move 3 pixels to the right (+3) and to the left (-3) same as up and down

Comment: I'm sorry because I'm kinda new in processing @VasylLyashkevych

Comment: I think do you need a code for your task, yes? How did you plan to show your results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

First off, you only have one `x` and `y` variable. You need to keep track of an `x` and `y` variable for **each word** instead. You could use arrays for that, or better yet you could [create a class](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-classes) that encapsulates a position and a word. (Shameless self-promotion: I wrote that tutorial, but I strongly recommend reading it as it contains examples that do almost everything you want to do.)

Secondly, you need to understand exactly what you're doing inside the `for` loop in the `draw()` function. Specifically what this line does:

```
int index = int(random(allWords.length));  //random selector of words
```

This is choosing a random index, but you're doing it inside a `for` loop inside the `draw()` function, so this is happening 50 times, 60 times per second. That's probably not what you want to do.

Instead, you probably just want to generate the random words **once** in the `setup()` function. You could do this by creating instances of the class you create and storing them in an array or an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Yes, you are so helpful! and thank you for all of your advice! where can I also find your tutorial?

Comment: @Noobprocessor It's the [create a class](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-classes) link in my post.

Comment: oh okay thank youuu again so much

Comment: where can you suggest I put the loadstrings? in a class or just in setup? I know this is a noob question....

Comment: @Noobprocessor Honestly you should put it wherever it makes sense to you. What happened when you tried putting it in `setup()`? What happened when you tried putting it in a separate class?

Comment: I'm trying to first convert it all with the class function but I keep getting a 'NullPointerException' error on display? did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Noobprocessor It's really hard to help you without seeing your code. If you have follow-up questions, please post them in their own question posts, along with a [mcve], and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: okay thank you again you're such a big help

Comment: @Noobprocessor No problem. Note that you can [upvote or accept answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you found them helpful. :p

Comment: yup tried to upvote but it says that "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." anyways I accepted it already! :)

Comment: last question but do you happen to also have like a link on how to do the "Instead, you probably just want to generate the random words once in the setup() function. You could do this by creating instances of the class you create and storing them in an array or an ArrayList." so I could have a guide on how I could start that?